# How can I scrape the content of this specific website (cineatlas)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the content of this particular website : https://www.cineatlas.com/

I tried scraping the date part as shown in the print screen :

[image]

I used this basic beautifulsoup code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
type(soup)
time = soup.find('ul',class_='slidee')
```

This is what I get instead of the list of elements

```
<ul class="slidee">
<!-- adding dates -->
</ul>
```

Comment: bs doesnt run js code, so if the page is dynamically generated using js you wont get it, you will need something that mimics a browser, [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/javascript-dynamic-scraping-parsing-beautiful-soup-tutorial/) is a random tutorial that shows how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site creates HTML elements dynamically from the Javascript content. You can get the JS content by using `re` for example:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from ast import literal_eval

url = 'https://www.cineatlas.com/'

html_data = requests.get(url).text
movieData = re.findall(r'movieData = ({.*?}), movieDataByReleaseDate', html_data, flags=re.DOTALL)[0]
movieData = re.sub(r'\s*/\*.*?\*/\s*', '', movieData)   # remove comments
movieData = literal_eval(movieData) # in movieData you have now the information about the current movies

print(json.dumps(movieData, indent=4))  # print data to the screen
```

Prints:

```
{
    "2019-08-06": [
        {
            "url": "fast--furious--hobbs--shaw",
            "image-portrait": "https://d10u9ygjms7run.cloudfront.net/dd2qd1xaf4pceqxvb41s1xpzs0/1562603443098_891497ecc8b16b3a662ad8b036820ed1_500x735.jpg",
            "image-landscape": "https://d10u9ygjms7run.cloudfront.net/dd2qd1xaf4pceqxvb41s1xpzs0/1562603421049_7c233477779f25725bf22aeaacba469a_700x259.jpg",
            "title": "FAST &amp; FURIOUS : HOBBS &amp; SHAW",
            "releaseDate": "2019-08-07",
            "endpoint": "ST00000392",
            "duration": "120 mins",
            "rating": "Classification TOUT",
            "director": "",
            "actors": "",
            "times": [
                {
                    "time": "7:00pm",
                    "bookingLink": "https://ticketing.eu.veezi.com/purchase/8388?siteToken&#x3D;b4ehk19v6cqkjfwdsyctqra72m",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5d468c20f67cc430833a5a2b",
                            "shortName": "VF",
                            "description": "Version Fran\u00e7aise"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5d468c20f67cc430833a5a2a",
                            "shortName": "3D",
                            "description": "3D"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "time": "9:50pm",
                    "bookingLink": "https://ticketing.eu.veezi.com/purchase/8389?siteToken&#x3D;b4ehk19v6cqkjfwdsyctqra72m",

... and so on.
```

Comment: it's very useful code. But the purpose is to scrape from the specific website rather than its sources

Comment: @M-Wane BeautifulSoup cannot execute Javascript, so in this case it's not useful. You may try `selenium` to scrape dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

```
lis = time.findChildren()
```

This returns a list of child nodes

Comment: didn't return anything :(

Comment: Did you try printing `lis`?